# npm link with git-style sub commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, node-commander

I'm having a problem using `npm link` with a nodejs cli tool built using [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js).

Using commander to make a git-style sub command style cli tool I have these files:

foo.js

foo-config.js

And foo.js (the main file looks like this)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node  
'use strict';

var program = require('commander');
var pkg = require('./package.json');

program
  .version(pkg.version)
  .command('config', 'Creates default configuration files')
  .parse(process.argv);
```

My package.json has this config

```
"bin": {
  "foo": "foo.js"
}
```

When I run `npm link` it successfully makes the symlink. I can even run the command and see that the `config` cmd shows up in the help menu.

However when I try to run `$ foo config` I get the following message

```
foo-config(1) does not exist, try --help
```

What do I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `foo-config.js` should be named `foo-config` without the extension.

Also if installing globally all the executables should be chmod 755

Answer (score 1):

I do it including all of commands in package.json bin section. In your example:

```
"bin": {
    "foo": "foo.js",
    "foo-config": "foo-config.js"
}
```

With this configuration, npm link will install all executables and all commands will work.

Comment: I also had to add shebang to the first line of `foo-config.js`: `#!/usr/bin/env node`